# Groovy If condition vs Java's if condition

Tags: java, groovy, dynamic

When I run this code in Groovy, it runs successfully. It even compiles successfully using `groovyc`.

```
if (2<3 || a_variable_not_defined_anywhere) {
  println "This is still working"
}
```

This prints out the output same as print statement. I understand that when first condition in "or" condition is successful, it will not even check the second condition.

But a similar "If" structure in Java errors out saying that variable is not defined.

My question is why it is running in Groovy and not in Java? When both are compiled languages.
Even in Python the above "If" structure works, but Python is Interpreted in nature.
Or does this have to do with the fact that both Groovy and Python are Dynamic in nature?

Can someone please clarify this?
Thanks

Update: With respect to bindings, I tried this code:

```
if (2<3 || a_variable_not_defined_anywhere) {
  println "This is still working"
}
a = 2
println binding.variables
```

This actually printed "a" as binding variables but not "a_variable_not_defined_anywhere"

So not sure it has anything to do with bindings here.

Comment: Quick note: Variable "a_variable_not_defined_anywhere" is not defined prior in code script

Comment: Whether or not it's "compiled" isn't super relevant, it has to do with language semantics. Groovy **could** do the same thing, but see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-98 from a long time ago.

Comment: If I do println(foo) in Groovy Console, it does give No Such Property Excecption or even when I do so in groovysh.

Comment: Right, but as you noted it's not being evaluated. If you swap the `||` you get the property exception.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But if it is the way I described in question, shouldn't this throw Property Not Found exception or something?

Comment: I don't think so, because if it isn't evaluated there's nothing to throw the exception. Properties are looked up w/ `getProperty`, if it's not called, it won't know it doesn't exist. It's not the same as a variable. Scripts have a root object that props are stuck onto (you can see what's happening if you decompile the byte code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy script the variable `a_variable_not_defined_anywhere` *could* be defined at runtime in `binding.variables` (see [binding](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html)). The binding context for the script is determined at runtime, therefore it compiles. At runtime, the second condition of the or statement is not executed, as already mentioned.

The point is that you *could* inject the variable before executing the script.
In Java, there is no binding. So the compiler knows already at compile time that something's off and throws an exception.

**EDIT**: Hopefully, this example makes it a bit clearer than the one before:

```
    // Let's say this is your code:
    String code = "println(a)"
    // Variable "a" is not defined, but the code compiles
    // in Groovy, because "a" could exist at runtime
  
    def sh = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding([a: "Hello World"]))
    // Here, "a" exists at runtime -> the code runs just fine.
    sh.evaluate(code)

    def shRuntimeError = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding([:]))
    // Here, "a" does not exist at runtime -> throws MissingPropertyException.
    shRuntimeError.evaluate(code)
```

Comment: if (2<3 || a_variable_not_defined_anywhere) {
  println "This is still working"
}
a = 2
println(binding.variables)








This prints "a" in binding variables but not the "a_variable_not_defined_anywhere"

I was aware of bindings but I don't think that is the case here

Comment: Updated my original question for better code readability.

Comment: The code does not compile in Java, but it does in Groovy, because for Groovy, there is the possibility the variable "a_variable_not_defined_anywhere" could exist at runtime in binding. That is the difference. At runtime, the variables in binding are only accessed when needed.

Comment: Edited my answer with a hopefully better example.